# Exporting Figma design into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, figma

Im trying to export the figma design I got into android studio. All the tutorials I ran over are using the plugin "Export Kit". However, when I try to export I get the following error:

[image]

Where am I making a mistake, is there another way to export the design I have ?